# Tensorflow epoch_loss becomes zero on the second epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using python 2.7 and I really don't understand why I am getting this.
I am guessing the problem is my python 2.7 is causing a float type problem.

```
('Epoch', 1, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 49576.683227539062)
('Epoch', 2, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 3, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 4, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 5, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 6, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 7, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 8, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 9, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Epoch', 10, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', 0.0)
('Accuracy:', 1.0)
```

My code is like the following:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i=0
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, # substitute batch_x into it
                                                          y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+=batch_size

            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))
```

Comment: What are your model, prediction and test data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kenny. My test data are two txt files that contain positive sentiment words and negative sentiment words. And it is going to predict a sentence whether it is belong to the postive or negative category. My model is exactly the same as this one. [Model and prediction](https://pythonprogramming.net/train-test-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/?completed=/preprocessing-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/)

Comment: Your indentation is wrong and the variables `hm_epoches`, `batch_size`, `train_x`, and `train_y` are not defined.

Comment: Hi MaxPower, thanks for your prompt reply, my indentation is okay but I just paste it incorrectly on here. Sorry for the ambiguous. I have defined it exactly like this link but I am still getting the error. [Original Code](https://pythonprogramming.net/train-test-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/?completed=/preprocessing-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you fit the data nearly perfect and the rounding makes it go to 0.0. You could try to use your loss function on the test set to see the output or print intermediate outputs of every iteration to see if the loss is decreasing as it should.

I would not worry about this though, because your test accuracy is 100% and therefore optimal. What more would you want?

Comment: I agree that my result is showing a 1.0 accuracy and therefore it is zero now. However, the tutorial shows a gradual decrease. I think I will have to check out intermediate output of cost and see if it is decreasing or not. Thank you Thomas!

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the answer now, one of the input text file was empty. I was so stupid.